# How to add material-icons to React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have tried

```
<Navbar.Collapse>
     <Nav>
         <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
             <i className="material-icons">face</i>Home
         </NavItem>
     </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
```

But not working.
Linked the font cdn from `public/index.html` with the following link
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-material-icons

use it as follows.

```
import MaterialIcon from 'react-google-material-icons'

<MaterialIcon icon="account_box" size={36}/>
```